# NSDate keeps returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

when the user clicks on a button it will get todays date/time. The start date and end date are returning nil

I have these instance variables:

```
@property (strong) NSDate *startingDate;
@property (strong) NSDate *endingDate;
@property (strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
```

in my init method:

```
    startingDate = [NSDate date];
    endingDate = [startingDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
```

Now my update method:

```
-(void)updateCountdown {

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"]; //format date for minutes and seconds

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

NSInteger minutes = [dateComponants minute];
NSInteger seconds = [dateComponants second];

NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d Minute %d Seconds", minutes, seconds];
timeLabel.text = countdownText;

NSLog (@"Startdate is %@ and Enddate is %@.", startingDate, endingDate);
NSLog(countdownText);

[self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

My problem now is that the startDate and endDate both return nil?

Edit: thanks for everyone who answered, it was intact my init not being called,

I had to add:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

if (self) {
    startingDate = [NSDate date];
    endingDate = [startingDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
}
```

Comment: What class is this code a subclass of and what is the precise name of the `init` method?

Comment: Try to add @synthesize startingDate, endDate in your implementation. Or access your values by _startingDate or self.startingDate.

Comment: my init method: 

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        startingDate = [NSDate date];
        endingDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: Hi tyt, I have synthesised them

Comment: And are those methods being executed? (check with breakpoint)

Comment: I find just too possibilities: 1. your init code does not get called, 2. your startingDate & endDate are not @synthezied to have setter method in order to modify theses instances by using your way.

Comment: If the properties were not synthesized, this code would not build, as it would not recognize what `startingDate` and `endingDate` were (as opposed to `_startingDate` or `self.startingDate`)

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback, I thought the init method gets called automatically?

Comment: The `initWithNibName` method will only be called if that's how you create your class. For instance, when creating your class, if you only do `MyClass *controller = [[MyClass alloc] init];` then `initWithNibName` will not be called. You need to do `MyClass *controller = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:"MyClassNibName"];`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I've just left home, so I will have to check this later, but from my NSLog I did before it looked like the init wasn't being called, so looks like this is the answer I hope, thank you

Comment: @tyt_g207 `@synthesize` isn't necessary to synthesize setters and getters for a non-dynamic property.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, it was the init method not being called and as i'm using a storyboard I've used: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder. I now have other problems and have edited my original post

Comment: Err, and if we fix that issue (via comments) will you re-edit your question with your next issue?  You can see the problem here, can't you?

Comment: Okay... I thought it might be better than starting a new thread but I can do that just as easily then and change my question back and set it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not doing the initialisation using the `initWithCoder` method, and calling the `initWithFrame` method.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
```

is what you are using, and gets called when using a xib or a storyboard.

the method :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect )frame
```

is what is called when you initialise the views programmatically. try implementing the init code is a separate method, and call it from both initWithCoder and initWithFrame. 
This way you will get the same behaviour from both kinds of calls.